# dll link error in visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am creating a dll+lib in one project and trying to use the function in that in another project.

Project_A:

```
fileA.h:

#ifdef COMPILE_A
#define A_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define A_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

 class A_EXPORT Class_A
   {
     void printFunction();
    }


fileA.cpp:

#include "fileA.h"
void fileA::printFunction()
{
   cout<<"bla bla";
}
```

Project_B:

```
fileB.cpp

#include "fileA.h"
int main()
{
  fileA obj();
  obj.printFunction();
 }
```

In pre-processor definition of fileA.cpp, I defined COMPILE_A. THis project gets compiled and produces a dll and lib file.

THen I link this to Project_B by linking the .lib file from the build of Project_A. I also linked the header files within Project_B.

I could import these header files and it compiles.
But when I try calling the printFucntion(), I get

Error   1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall

kind of error.

Can anyone help me out of this?

Comment: DLLs are like pointers, an extra level of indirection that never stops causing confusion.  Rough symptom is that you are not actually linking the import library.  Obfuscating names and not posting the *exact* error message doesn't help us help you.

Comment: There is no class `fileA` in this code, yet apparently it has a member `void fileA::printFunction()`. Post *real* code with the *real* error message (verbatim).

Answer (score 0):

I used the wizard to create sample projects.  To resolve linked errors, I had to add a reference in the file_b project to the file_a project.

Also, the code didn't compile the line

```
   fileA obj();
```

you probably want

```
   fileA obj;
```

See the TwoProj project under https://github.com/kc1073/Samples/ for the complete VS solution.

KC